PowerBI query similar to sumif in excel
Columns named a, b, c. Column a contains dates I want to add column c value as long as dates in column a are same then find unique values in column b as long as dates in column a are same then divide output from column b with output of column c

It's easy using pivot table in Excel, but I have no idea how to do that in PowerBI - please help me.

The first thing you might want to do is apply some punctuation to your question, so that it can be understood at first read, instead of having to go over and over it to figure out where one statement ends and the next one starts. While you're editing your question, describe what you have already tried and what issues you have run into.

try to create two measure
Measure = sum('Table'[time])/DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[type])

Measure 2 = sumx(VALUES('Table'[date]),[Measure])

screenshot of ouptut
